# Why am I stuck when I try to improve someone's edit?

Tags: support, quality-improvement

On any question I try to *improve edit*, this happens:

Question 1:
[image: Question 1]

Question 2:
[image: Question 2]

It gets stuck at "Improving..."

I am able to use the rest of the site. Only *improve edit* has a problem. It is stuck on that page (been 10 minutes now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scroll down, there is another button - 'Save Edits'. I've been bitten by this one before, too.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, did that after about 20mins. But why does it get stuck, any idea?

Comment: @AniMenon I'm not sure what you mean by getting stuck.. it's waiting for you to submit the edits. It's probably a UI flaw that it looks like a button, but it's simply an indication that the review is being worked on.

Comment: I meant no response. That is I do the edit & submit then it show "Improving..", then doesn't move forward. Now its working for me. Thanx.