# Is the improve button disabled on purpose in certain suggested-edit reviews?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I was trying to improve this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12447866), but the improve button is disabled.
I also tried Reject & Edit with the same result.

Is this a bug, or did I do something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Not reproduced in FF 48.0a2 on Linux Mint 17.3.

Comment: Well, I could improve it! FF44 Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Related? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323335/why-am-i-stuck-when-i-try-to-improve-someones-edit According to the comments on the answer, it wasn't working, then started working. (At least, that's my reading of it. The OP wasn't ever super clear.)

Comment: Yeah @Kendra that is it ...

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding here. You are *currently* improving the post. When you are finished, you scroll down and hit "Save Edits" - you don't hit the button at the top.

Comment: Maybe they should just humor us and allow us to save edits with either button...

Comment: @Laurel A tool tip would have been enough for me.